# Magento - Product Collection with the current user's Wishlist

Tags: magento

Within a Magento php Controller, how can I get a Product Collection containing the products listed in the logged in user's (ie current user's) Wishlist.

I am getting the Wishlist using:

```
$wishList = Mage::getModel('wishlist/wishlist')->loadByCustomer(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer());
```

and this contains the correct number of items.

But I would like to get a Product Collection. I have tried:

```
$productCollection = $wishList->getProductCollection();
```

and

```
$productCollection = $wishList->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('id')->load();
```

but the Product Collection I get has a length of 0.

How do I get the Product Collection?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [getWishlistItemCollection](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Wishlist/Mage_Wishlist_Helper_Data.html#methodgetWishlistItemCollection) (see link for more details) off the wishlist helper to return a collection of items, you then need to get the product from the item.

I have been using the following code to create an associative array of the products, which I then use to determine if a product I am displaying in the list page is in the wishlist...hopefully this will help:

```
public function getWishList() {
    $_itemCollection = Mage::helper('wishlist')->getWishlistItemCollection();
    $_itemsInWishList = array();

    foreach ($_itemCollection as $_item) {
        $_product = $_item->getProduct();

        $_itemsInWishList[$_product->getId()] = $_item;
    }

    return $_itemsInWishList;   
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this with product all details like name, images etc...

```
<?php
 $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
 if($customer->getId())
{
     $wishlist = Mage::getModel('wishlist/wishlist')->loadByCustomer($customer, true);
     $wishListItemCollection = $wishlist->getItemCollection();
     foreach ($wishListItemCollection as $item)
     {
           echo $item->getName()."</br>";
           echo $item->getId()."</br>";
           echo $item->getPrice()."</br>";
           echo $item->getQty()."</br>";  
           $item = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId($item->getStoreId())->load($item->getProductId());
          if ($item->getId()) :
?>
<img src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($item, 'small_image')->resize(113, 113); ?>" width="113" height="113" />
<?php endif; } } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();

$wishlist = Mage::getModel('wishlist/wishlist')->loadByCustomer($customer, true);

$wishListItemCollection = $wishlist->getItemCollection();

foreach ($wishListItemCollection as $item)
{
   // do things
}
```